# Artifactory downloads file with 0 bytes

Tags: curl, artifactory

I'm writing a CI/CD pipeline in GitLab for an android application. I use Artifactory to push my '.apk' files as intermediary storage. From there I'm distributing to the Firebase distribution server.

In the above mentioned workflow, I can upload the file (apk) to the Artifactory without any issues. I use this command to do that:

```
curl -uusername:token -T file.apk "https://domain-name.jfrog.io/artifactory/folder/file.apk
```

The upload works fine. I can manually download the file from the console, if required. But when I try to download the file, the file gets downloaded but shows only 0B in size. I'm using this command to download the file:

```
curl -sSf -uusername:token -O '"https://domain-name.jfrog.io/artifactory/folder/file.apk'
```

Am I missing something or did I do something wrong.

Comment: Can you try adding `-L` to the `curl` command? (follow redirects)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Don't know why it is not mentioned by JFrog. I have been directly following the documentation and it is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Cool! Glad it worked. Can you share the doc link you used?

Comment: Yeah sure. This is the link that I used: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Usage. And in that, I used this link to retrieve artifacts. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveArtifact

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment from @Eldad Assis answers my question. It seems the -L option with curl command works. At final, this is the command that I used to download the artifact from JFrog artifactory:

```
curl -L -u${JFROG_USERNAME}:${JFROG_TOKEN} \
      -X GET "https://domain-name.jfrog.io/artifactory/folder/file.apk" \
      --output file.apk
```